# How to fill a Tikz path, for which anchors are not defined by coordinates but by nodes

Tags: fill, tikz-path

I am trying to add a path in a tikzpicture.
The area surrounded by the path shall be colored, i.e., filled in a color.

I would like to use nodes as anchors for the path, rather than x, y coordinates.

The following code snippet does, unfortunately, not produce a colored area.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,matrix,patterns,chains,positioning,shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\node[](start) at (0,0) {};
\node[right=2cm of start](first) {};
\node[above=2cm of first](second) {};
\node[left=2cm of second](third) {};
 
\path[draw=black,fill=red] (start) -- (first) -- (second) -- (third) -- (start);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I was playing around with the inner sep and outer sep of the nodes, but that did not help.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Hi, welcome. You can specify the anchor of the nodes, i.e. `(start.center) -- (first.center) -- ` and so on, but there is a special type of node for just this sort of thing: `\coordinate`. So do `\coordinate (start); \coordinate[right=2cm of start] (first);` and so on, then the filling will work.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much!